# Can someone explain how wiki got Canonical basis equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, canonical-transformation

[image: Copied From Wikipedia]

Thank you so much.

Link: [Canonical basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_basis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [definition of a generalized eigenvector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector#Overview_and_definition) linked in the passage that you posted.

A rank $k$ generalized eigenvector $x$ for eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ satisfies $(A-\lambda_i I)^kx=0$ and $(A-\lambda_i I)^{k-1} x \ne 0$.

So, the rank $k$ generalized eigenvectors consist of everything in the nullspace of $(A-\lambda_i I)^k$ that is not in the nullspace of $(A-\lambda_i I)^{k-1}$. But the latter nullspace is contained in the former.

So, $\rho_k$ is $\text{null}((A-\lambda_i I)^k) - \text{null}((A-\lambda_i I)^{k-1})$. Applying the rank-nullity theorem gives the expression in your post.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! How can I understand "the latter nullspace is contained in the former"? Why can some vector x can also make $(A-λ_iI)^{k-1}x = 0$? Thanks!

Comment: @LiseLöwe If $(A-\lambda_i I)^{k-1} v=0$, then $(A-\lambda_i I)^kv=0$, so $\text{nullspace}((A-\lambda_i I)^{k-1}) \subset \text{nullspace}((A-\lambda_i I)^{k})$.